# There has been an error processing your request. Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a similar issue please see log. Could someone please assist.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:65:"dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract";i:1;s:1471:"#0 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#2 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#3 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#4 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#5 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#6 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#7 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#8 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#9 /home/cubcoza/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/cubcoza/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/robots.txt";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the root of your Magento setup there is one folder "errors". You will find one file "local.xml.sample" in that folder. Rename it to "local.xml" and refresh the page and see what error it is showing on page. You might be get closer to error.

Comment: Note that any changes that cause Magento to openly display any stack traces must be reversed. Otherwise you will be breaking **PCI DSS SAQ-D 5.6.6** by leaking error message information. 

Stack traces include neat things like your database credentials and other things that criminals need to know.

Enabling breaking PCI DSS without proper warning also tells you if a Magento developer is capable of producing secure websites. If they're quick to jump in and recommend anything but going and looking at the file saved in its standard place, watch out.